# only insert variables which have values, not undefined node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

So i have this:

```
var dates = {
    monday: req.body.monday,
    tuesday: req.body.tuesday,
    wednesday: req.body.wednesday,
    thursday: req.body.thursday,
    friday: req.body.friday,
    saturday: req.body.saturday,
    sunday: req.body.sunday
}

    console.log(Object.values(dates))
```

the way this works is you can select a checkbox on the front end, and all the results will be sent to the backend regardless if you checked it or not. Now, i need to sort through those results to only insert the ones that were selected (they don't have defined values, like the array response below).

in the for loop result set, i it gets returned as so:

```
    [
  '2',       undefined,
  undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined,
  '1'
    ]
```

as you can see, 5/7 are undefined. So i have a standard insert query into SQL, but i need to insert only the values that are defined.
so in my head i am thinking `insert into clients where Object.values(dates) != undefined`, but i know thats not right, especially cause that's now the way the `sql` query works lol.

I have this:

```
var addclient = "insert into clients (NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, TRAINER_NAME, HOUR, MINUTE, DATES) values ('" + name + "', '" + email + "', '" + phonenumber + "', '" + req.session.username + "', '" + hour + "', '" + minute + "', '" + dates + "')";
```

how can i do this?

Comment: What are you expecting "dates" to be turned into for the string in the database?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, for example what's the type of `DATES` in the DB ? from the query you put one would assume it's a JSON.
Is the query executed in a loop ?

Comment: @Digglit just updated to explain more.

Comment: @developerg1000 it's still unclear as to what you're hoping the end result in your database will look like. Can you post an example of what a string will appear as?

Comment: If you want your array to just have the values that are not undefined, just filter them out. `console.log(Object.values(dates).filter(el=> !!el))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're hoping to insert the values as a comma delineated string, you can accomplish that by doing the following:

```
const formattedString = Object.values(dates).filter(el => el).join(', ');
var addclient = "insert into clients (NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, TRAINER_NAME, HOUR, MINUTE, DATES) values ('" + name + "', '" + email + "', '" + phonenumber + "', '" + req.session.username + "', '" + hour + "', '" + minute + "', '" + formattedString + "')";
```

Notice that I changed the "dates" in your insert method to the new "formattedString". Given your example, formattedString would be "2, 1".

Answer (score 1):

Besides the actual question, using unsanitzed input to create a sql string in the way it is shown in the snippet is a huge risk. It allows an attacker to perform a sql injection. See more here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection